# Can't marry GIN and custom bean validator in GWT application (compiler error)

Tags: gwt, bean-validation, gwt2, gwt-gin

Could you guys help me marry GIN and custom bean validator in GWT application (GWT 2.4) ?

GWT compiler gives me following errors:

```
Rebind result 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' must be a class
Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.ProviderValidationMessageResolver' must be a class
```

My GIN module looks like this

```
@GinModules(ClientGinModule.class)
public interface ClientGinjector extends Ginjector
{
    NewOrderView getOrderView();
}
```

Where `NewOrderView` just extends `Composite`.

In my `.gwt.xml` of my module I have following instructions

```
<replace-with class="com.mine.courierApp.client.validation.ClientValidatorFactory">
    <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory"/>
</replace-with>
<replace-with class="com.mine.courierApp.client.validation.ClientValidationMessagesResolver">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.validation.client.UserValidationMessagesResolver"/>
</replace-with>
```

So I thought maybe GIN wants to know this in Java code so I modified my GIN module which became

```
public class ClientGinModule extends AbstractGinModule
{
    protected void configure()
    {
        bind(javax.validation.ValidatorFactory.class).to(ClientValidatorFactory.class);
        bind(com.google.gwt.validation.client.UserValidationMessagesResolver.class).to(ClientValidationMessagesResolver.class);
    }
}
```

But it didn't help although error message became bigger:

```
Rebind result 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' must be a class
Rebind result 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' must be a class
Cannot proceed due to previous errors
Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.ProviderValidationMessageResolver' must be a class
```

Update: Detailed GWT compiler output:

```
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/BaseMessageInterpolator.java'
      [ERROR] Line 96:  Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.ProviderValidationMessageResolver' must be a class
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/GwtValidatorContext.java'
      [ERROR] Line 36:  Rebind result 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' must be a class
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/validation/client/spi/GwtValidationProvider.java'
      [ERROR] Line 39:  Rebind result 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' must be a class
   [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
```

What shall I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out I have to define

```
<replace-with class="com.mine.courierApp.client.validation.ClientValidatorFactory">
    <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory"/>
</replace-with>
<replace-with class="com.mine.courierApp.client.validation.ClientValidationMessagesResolver">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.validation.client.UserValidationMessagesResolver"/>
</replace-with>
```

in all gwt modules, even in those that don't use validation at all.